# How can I use validation with form without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a jQuery for mobile number validation without page refresh on <kbd>submit</kbd> button but it is not working and when I click the <kbd>submit</kbd>button. But with page refresh it works.

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Submit Form Without Refreshing Page</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/refreshform.css" />
        <script src="js/fresh.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="mainform">

            <!-- Required div starts here -->

            <form id="form">

                <label>First Name:</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name"/><br/>
                <br/>
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/><br/>
                <br/>
                <label>MobliNo:</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Your MobNo"/><br/>
                <br/>
                <label>ConfirmMobliNo:</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="remobile" placeholder="Confirm MobNo"/><br/>
                <br/>
                <label>Email:</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"/><br/>
                <br/>
                        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick = "return Validate()"/>
            </form>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**refresh.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#submit").click(function(){
var fname = $("#fname").val();
var lname = $("#lname").val();
var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
var remobile = $("#remobile").val();
var email = $("#email").val();


// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("refreshform.php",{ fname1: fname, lname1: lname, mobile1: mobile, remobile1: remobile, email1: email},
            function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#form')[0].reset(); //To reset form fields
            });


});
});

 function Validate() {
        var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
        var pattern = /^\d{10}$/;
        if (pattern.test(mobile)) {
            alert("Your mobile number : " + mobile);
            return true;
        }
        alert("It is not valid mobile number.input 10 digits number!");
        return false;
    }
```

What should I do to achieve validation without page refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in a slight different way. Remove

```
onclick = "return Validate()"
```

from the button and put that inside the click function like this

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
   var valid = Validate();
   if(valid){
     /// Then your rest of process here.
   }
});
```

Hope that works.

This will just check whether the phone number has 10 digits

```
function Validate() {
    var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    var remobile = document.getElementById("remobile").value;

    if(isNaN(mobile) || isNaN(remobile)){
        alert("Invalid. Mobile and re mobile should be numbers only.");
        return false;
    }
    if(mobile.length != 10){
        alert("Invalid number. It should be 10 digits only.");
        return false;
    }
    if(remobile.length != 10){
        alert("Invalid Re mobile number. It should be 10 digits only.");
        return false;
    }

    if(mobile != remobile){
        alert("Mobile and remobile does not match!");
        return false;
    }

    alert("Valid Number.");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this will not work if you just press enter button in form's text field

Comment: I strongly suggest never to attach submit event handlers to submit buttons but instead do `$("#form").on("submit",function(){`

Comment: @Lashane but he have input type button not submit so i think form will not submit on enter

Comment: it working but after diplaying a alert box it submitting form

Comment: Sheetal it seems that your validate function is not working properly.

Comment: Sheetal How do you want to validate phone number ?? I mean only integers and 10 didgits ??

Comment: validation is  not working without page refresh why?

Comment: I have a sample page created which is working fine. Give your email ID I will send you that page.

Comment: same problem is here after displaying alert msg submitting form

Comment: shaktisharma27789@gmail.com

Comment: If you write a code which if condition meets will submit the submit the form. In my example it makes the ajax call and does not submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
   var fname = $("#fname").val();
   var lname = $("#lname").val();
   var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
   ....
```

should be

```
$('#form').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   if (Validate())
   {
     // Do the posting
     var fname = $("#fname").val();
     var lname = $("#lname").val();
     var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
     ....
```

or  *)

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   if (Validate())
   {
     // Do the posting
     var fname = $("#fname").val();
     var lname = $("#lname").val();
     var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
     ....
```

By including `event.preventDefault()` in the event handler, you block the default action for the element that triggered the *event*. In this case, the default action is submitting the form, so without this change, the form will still be submitted in the normal way, after it is submitted through AJAX.

*) *Side note:* `on` is a bit more flexible for binding events. You can also specify a selector as the second parameter. This way, you can set an event handler in the document (or another containing element), which will automatically be called for events on any child element that matches the given selector. This is especially useful if you have dynamic pages where elements are added or removed, because you won't have to add the event handlers every time you add an element. In this particular case it won't matter much, but I thought I'd let you know. The syntax for that is:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(event){
```

Comment: this will not work if you just press enter button in form's text field

Answer (score 0):

in you form use:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return Validate();">
```

and button just submit:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

in your js validate code instead of `return true`

```
var fname = $("#fname").val();
var lname = $("#lname").val();
var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
var remobile = $("#remobile").val();
var email = $("#email").val();


// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("refreshform.php",{ fname1: fname, lname1: lname, mobile1: mobile, remobile1: remobile, email1: email},
            function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#form')[0].reset(); //To reset form fields
            });

return false;
```

in this case you will submit form without page refresh

Comment: @mplungjan in original Validate function

Comment: Ah, I mixed yours and another answer since I expected the inline handler to be removed

Answer (score -2):

```
function Validate() {
     var mob = /^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/;
     if (mob.test($.trim($("#<%=mobile.ClientID %>").val())) == false) {
    alert("Please enter valid mobile number.");
    $("#<%=mobile.ClientID %>").focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is call textbox mobile input id.